# Retain data unique to page in Chrome Extension's popup?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, popup, local-storage

I feel like I'm missing something incredibly obvious here.
I am building a Chrome Extension, and I want to be able to retain data specific to the page being viewed that affects the popup.html.

A simple example would follow these steps:
- Open a tab to google.com
- Click Extension icon to open Popup, background is blue.
- Save note to localStorage that Popup has opened.  Close Popup.
- Open Popup again, background is green because of localStorage setting.
- Open a tab to yahoo.com

When I open the popup on the yahoo.com tab, I want the background to be blue, but localStorage is specific to the popup, not to the tab so the background will actually be green.

How can I store data in the popup that is specific to the tab the user is viewing?

Comment: I just discovered `chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) { console.log(tab); })` will give me information about the currently selected tab...so I should probably be able to figure it out from here.

Comment: You cannot programatically hide/show the extension pop-up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reposting from the comments above:

> I just discovered chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) { console.log(tab); }) will give me information about the currently selected tab...so I should probably be able to figure it out from here.